# NGINX with uwsgi and django connection refused

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

Welcome stackoverflowers. I`ve been fighting with setting up nginx with uwsgi with django app... There has to be a small mistake somewhere but I cant find it. Here is my file from pastebin, containing files directly related to my issue and also a console log. I would be very greateful if somebody could take a look and help me out.

**artcolor_uwsgi.ini file**

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/
module          = artcolor.wsgi
home            = /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/artcolor_venv/

master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/artcolor.sock
#http-socket = :8001

#vacuum          = true
```

**artcolor_nginx.conf file**

```
upstream django {
    server /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/artcolor.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8001;
    server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    access_log /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/logs/nginx-error.log;


    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 1G;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media/  {
        alias /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/media/;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include    uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

**wsgi.py file**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/")
sys.path.append("/home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/artcolor/")

sys.path = sys.path[::-1]

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "artcolor.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**my console**

```
(artcolor_venv)seb@debian:~/pypassion/artcolor/src$ uwsgi --ini artcolor_uwsgi.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from artcolor_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Fri Feb 27 11:48:45 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 27 February 2015 11:00:34
os: Linux-3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2
nodename: debian
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src
detected binary path: /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/artcolor_venv/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/
your processes number limit is 63796
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/src/artcolor.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:26:58)  [GCC 4.7.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/seb/pypassion/artcolor/artcolor_venv/
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x20e9d30
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 800448 bytes (781 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x20e9d30 pid: 14848 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 14848)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14849, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 14850, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 14851, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 14852, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 14853, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 14854, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 14855, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 14856, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 14857, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 14858, cores: 1)
```

**SOLVED
I linked my nginx file to sites-available not as I was supossed to sites-enabled**

Comment: How do you try to connect your server? What does nginx error log say?

Comment: "Connection refused" indicates that the port you're trying to access is not open or there might be a firewall in front. I see your nginx is listening on port 8001. Is this also the port you're accessing? Do you maybe have yet another server such as a load balancer or cache, proxying from port 80 to port 8001?

Comment: first of all i start my nginx
then im running uwsgi --ini artcolor_uwsgi.ini
next step is to run localhost:8001 (because my nginx is listening on that port) and It should redirect me to my artcolor.sock

I've checked and there is nothing else on 8001, I`ve changed it to 9015 and restarted my nginx and nothing has changed.

Comment: Also, ´server_name localhost;´. Is this not a production server? server_name should be the domain where the web is accessed from the outside.

Comment: for now I'm trying to add it to localhost, at my workstation localy.

When everything will be fine here, I'm moving it to production machine

Comment: Post the last few lines of NginX error log: `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: There are no error logs

Comment: Check your nginx access log to see if you're actually accessing it. You have it defined in your config.

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing it

http://pastebin.com/dUzwFxU1

Comment: And the error log is empty...

Comment: Can I please see the error log?

Comment: As I said it's empty

Comment: Error 400 is "bad request". Your web browser sends a request that is not understood by the server.

Comment: So in the browser, you don't get "connection refused" but "400 - bad request". In that case your title is misleading.

Comment: "Error Code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: In your browser I assume... Where are you getting that 400 then?

Comment: I missinterpreted that 400 error. It`s only ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: SOLUTION:

I linked my nginx conf file to sites-available not as I should sites-enabled

SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I managed to resolve problem.

The reason was wrong linking the nginx.conf file.

I accidently linked in to `sites-available`, not as I was supposed to `sites-enabled`

Thanks